# Array handling issue in TCL script

Tags: tcl

I am having one list as stated below

```
echo $mem_ip_list2 

sdmmc dpram eth ram1 usbhs sram cmcc tag cmcc data tram mem flexram 8k32 flexram 4k32
```

This is having pair of two strings

```
key   value 
sdmmc dpram
eth   ram1
usbhs sram 
cmcc tag
cmcc data
tram mem 
flexram 8k32
flexram 4k32
```

I need to create an array and print the values as shown in the script

The script which I have written is

```
array set array1 $mem_ip_list2

SETUP> foreach { q z } [array get array1 ] {
puts " ip : $q , mem : $z "
}
```

Output of this script

```
ip : tram , mem : mem
 ip : sdmmc , mem : dpram
 ip : usbhs , mem : sram
 ip : eth , mem : ram1
 ip : cmcc , mem : data
 ip : flexram , mem : 4k32
```

But two  key value pairs are missing which are repeated keys

```
flexram 8k32
cmcc tag
```

Could you help me out  by providing some insight on this ?

Comment: Keys, by definition, are unique

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot Jerry! But could we have some mechanism in place to achieve the desired result with arrays,

Comment: No, that's not the intended purpose of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't store it in an array. Use the original list as a list of key:value pairs:

```
set mem_ip_list2 {sdmmc dpram eth ram1 usbhs sram cmcc tag cmcc data tram mem flexram 8k32 flexram 4k32}
foreach {key value} $mem_ip_list2 {puts "ip : $key , mem : $value"}
```

```
ip : sdmmc , mem : dpram
ip : eth , mem : ram1
ip : usbhs , mem : sram
ip : cmcc , mem : tag
ip : cmcc , mem : data
ip : tram , mem : mem
ip : flexram , mem : 8k32
ip : flexram , mem : 4k32
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn , could able to proceed now .